# MySQL ORDER BY random field does not work with additional operation

Tags: mysql, sql

I face a strange behavior of MySQL. When I select a field that uses RAND() in its calculation and order the result by this field, everything works fine:

```
SELECT 
RAND() AS r
FROM SomeTable
ORDER BY r DESC;
```

If, however, I perform an additional operation within the ORDER BY clause such as +,-,*. / or whatever you like with a constant or another field, the result is no longer sorted. For example:

```
SELECT 
RAND() AS r
FROM SomeTable
ORDER BY r+1 DESC;
```

Of course I can move the operation in an additional field, but I was just curious whether I do something wrong. I assume that for some unknown reason MySQL re-evaluates the field if some operation is performed in the ORDER BY clause.

Is this a correct assumption???

Comment: In my opinion, this is a bug in MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MySQL 5.0 Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand):

> You cannot use a column with RAND() values in an ORDER BY clause,
>   because ORDER BY would evaluate the column multiple times.

`RAND()` is being evaluated every time it's called, even though you've aliased it as `r` it gets re-evaluated and does not hold the same value as the column.

If you want to `ORDER BY r+1` you'll need a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT col1, RAND() AS r
      FROM Table1
      ) sub
ORDER BY (r+1) DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reference. So you would also suggest to not select (r+1) as an additional column? I tested it and it works fine. So it seems in this case i will not be evaluated multiple times...

Comment: @user1488793 Yeah if you `SELECT RAND()+1 AS r1` then you can `ORDER BY r1` without it re-evaluating, I was thinking you needed `r` and `r+1` both.  If you `SELECT RAND() AS r, RAND()+1 AS r1` the difference between `r` and r1` will very rarely be 1.

Comment: I appreciate the attempt, but I don't see how this actually answers the question.  The OP doesn't have `rand()` in the `order by`.  The OP has an expression that references the `select`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It doesn't mention `RAND()` in the `ORDER BY` it says a column with `RAND()` values, which is what we've got here.  The documentation is at least a little unclear, `r` stays consistent but `r+0` is re-evaluated as a new column, but the documentation could be interpreted to indicate that the `r` should be re-evaluated too.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be caused by what other databases call "volatile" functions and MySQL calls "non-deterministic" functions.  These are functions that return different values each time they are called.

Based on your observation, your second query is being evaluated as:

```
SELECT RAND() AS r
FROM SomeTable
ORDER BY RAND() + 1 DESC;
```

That is, the *expression* for `r` is being plugged into the `ORDER BY`.  Because `rand()` is non-deterministic, it returns a different value each time it is called.  The result is a randomly ordered result set, but different from the ordering of the `r` column.

In my opinion, this is a bug in MySQL  It is using expression substitution for a function that is (or at least should be) declared `NOT DETERMINISTIC`.  The "bug" may simply be that the built-in `rand()` function is not properly declared as `not deterministic`.  It could be that the declaration is ignored.  Obviously, MySQL should be using the value that the alias refers to, rather than the expression, especially for a non-deterministic function.

Note:  This has a potential impact beyond deterministic functions.  If the expression is a complex, time-consuming expression, it may end up being evaluated multiple additional times for the `order by`.